# Yii2 dropDownList -Cannot insert data into database

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

Hi I add the dropdownlist to my _form before that i can still insert and submit data into database , but when I replaced my input with dropdownlist. everything is ok but when I click submit button no error displayed but no data inserted to database.How Can I fix this? Help me pleasee guys.. Thank you soo much.. in advance..
[This is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIJwa.png)

This is my Tblregion model

```
<?php

namespace backend\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "tbl_region".
 *

 */
class TblRegion extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'tbl_region';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['nregion_id'], 'required'],
            [['nregion_id'], 'integer'],
            [['cregion_procode', 'cregion_proaddress'], 'string', 'max' => 40],
            [['cregion_proname', 'cregion_prohead', 'cregion_tel', 'cregion_position', 'cregion_name'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'cregion_procode' => 'Cregion Procode',
            'cregion_proname' => 'Cregion Proname',
            'cregion_prohead' => 'Cregion Prohead',
            'cregion_proaddress' => 'Cregion Proaddress',
            'cregion_tel' => 'Cregion Tel',
            'cregion_position' => 'Cregion Position',
            'cregion_name' => 'Cregion Name',
            'nregion_id' => 'Region',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getTblProvinces()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TblProvince::className(), ['nregion_id' => 'nregion_id']);
    }
}


<?php

namespace backend\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "tbl_province".
 */
class TblProvince extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'tbl_province';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['nregion_id', 'cprovince_name'], 'required'],
            [['nregion_id'], 'integer'],
            [['cprovince_name'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['cprovince_areacode'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
            [['cprovince_code'], 'string', 'max' => 40],
            [['nregion_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => TblRegion::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['nregion_id' => 'nregion_id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [   
            'nregion_id' => 'Region Name',
            'cprovince_name' => 'Province Name',
            'cprovince_areacode' => 'Province Areacode',
            'cprovince_code' => 'Province Code',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getTblCities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TblCity::className(), ['cprovince_name' => 'cprovince_name']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getTblFacilities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TblFacility::className(), ['cprovince_name' => 'cprovince_name']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getregion()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(TblRegion::className(), ['nregion_id' => 'nregion_id']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show `tblregion` model.

Comment: @Bizley here is the models. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is exact problem here but you can check few things:

- Always use exact names - when model class name is `TblRegion` use `TblRegion` and not `tblregion`; Windows is not case sensitive but Linux systems are.
- You have not mentioned what model are you working with using this form but based on the fields' names I guess it's `TblProvince` - field `region` is not included in this model but you fill the dropdown with data: `nregion_id` => `cregion_name` so most probably you should rename this field:

  ```
  <?= $form->field($model, 'nregion_id')->dropDownList(
      ArrayHelper::map(TblRegion::find()->all(), 'nregion_id', 'cregion_name'), 
      ['prompt' => 'Select Region']
  ) ?>
  ```

Comment: NO. I mean the region  is come from model TblProvince and it has  function   public function getregion()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(TblRegion::className(), ['nregion_id' => 'nregion_id']);
    }

Answer (score 0):

The answer is.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'nregion_id')->dropDownList(
ArrayHelper::map(tblregion::find()->asArray()->all(),'nregion_id','nregion_id'),
['prompt'=>'Select Region'])?>
```

what my mistake is i use region instead of `nregion_id`.

I also add code `->asArray()`.

Thank guys..